# Why is the number repeating?

Tags: arrays, swift, sorting

My ultimate goal is to get an array of Ints extracted from a String inputted in a textfield. For this I created a function whose parameter is a String. I use a for-loop to get all the characters from the textfield into an array. Then I loop through the array and append only the numbers (if they're <= 24) to a new array. When I print the array with just numbers, I get the first element of array1 repeating. Why is this happening?

```
var array1 = [String]()
var array2 = [Int]()

func getDigits (userInput: String) {
    for element in userInput {
        array1.append(String(element))
    }
    var mx = 0
    var fx = 1
    func findNumbers() {
        for number in 1...24 {
            if array1[mx] == "\(fx)" {
                array2.append(Int(String(array1[mx]))!)
            } else {
                fx += 1
                findNumbers()
            }
        }
    }
findNumbers()
print (array2)
}
getDigits(userInput: "4-5")
```

Output: [4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4]

Comment: Use the debugger. Step through the code line by line and see your mistake.

Comment: Hint: what is `mx`, and what value will it contain?

Comment: @CharlesSrstka Thank you for your help! I don't understand your hint though. mx is just a counter

Comment: @Theodore.K But is it, though?

Comment: @CharlesSrstka Cus you're saying that I never += mx? Ya, I'm looking at my code now and trying to figure out what to do. I think I need to add another loop.

Comment: Yep, it's just `0` the whole time, which is why you always get the first element of `array1`.

Comment: @CharlesSrstka Thank you for pointing that out. Do you know how I can accomplish my goal? Like where to put the other loop? I was thinking an "else if" would work.

Comment: @Theodore.K Depends on what you're trying to do. The easiest and cleanest thing might actually be to get rid of the `mx` counter entirely and just iterate through `array1` using a `for`..`in` loop.

Comment: @Theodore.K Or even better, you might be able to find a way to do what you need inside a closure that you pass to `map` or `flatMap`/`compactMap`.

Comment: I edited your posted code, *only* removing the blank lines. Unless you made some errors on the code posted - or I did something very wrong with my edit - you have *at least* one problem - nested `func` declarations`. A second thing I'm seeing is recursive calls to `findNumbers`? Roll back my edit if you wish, or post your full code. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will support multi-digit numbers in your input string, and also filter out-of-range values.

```
import Foundation

func parseNumbers (userInput: String, splitBy: String, min: Int, max: Int) -> Array<Int> {
    let separators = CharacterSet(charactersIn: splitBy)
    let numericStrings = userInput.components(separatedBy: separators)

    var numArray = [Int]()

    for item in numericStrings {
        if let number = Int(item) {
            if (number >= min) && (number <= max) {
                numArray.append(number)
            }
        }
    }

    return numArray
}

print(parseNumbers(userInput: "5:hello,34-7 12;103,abc", splitBy: " -:,;", min:1, max:24))
```

output: [5, 7, 12]

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
func getDigits (userInput: String) {
   let splitsCharacters = ",;:- "
   let seperators = CharacterSet(charactersIn: splitsCharacters)
   let updateInput = userInput.components(separatedBy: seperators)
   print(array1)
   func findNumbers() {
      for item in updateInput {
          if let number = Int(item) {
              if  number <= 24{
                  array2.append(number)
              }
          }
      }
   }
   findNumbers()
   print (array2)
}
getDigits(userInput: "4-5 hello, 34;12,23")
```

**Output** : [4, 5,12,23]

Comment: You're a genius! Thank you!

Comment: Found an issue: it doesn't work for double digit numbers.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are trying to do but you can try something like

**Swift 4**

```
func getDigits (userInput: String) {
    var resultArray = [Int]()
    for char in userInput {
        if let number = Int("\(char)"), number < 24 {
            resultArray.append(number)
        }
    }

    print(resultArray)
}
```

testing

```
getDigits(userInput: "4-5")
//prints => [4, 5]
```

You need just 1 array to hold the numbers

Note: in swift for the string is array type so you can loop on it directly, but for earlier versions you can use:

```
for char in userInput.characters {

}
```

to get the array of string characters

Comment: Thank you for your help! However, this doesn't work for double digit numbers like "14-16"

Comment: yes, that's because you are checking on each single character.